# Single mode VS Multimode in a server room?

Tags: network

I do fiber internally for the company I work with. The only fiber I dont touch is Comcast in our buildings. Anyway, we recently switched to single mode and when talking to the LeCom guy (they do Comcast terminations for the most part) they were telling me they normally used multimode for runs that are short because single mode will burn out the optics over time if it doesn't have an LC Attenuator (we use lc to lc everything). Should we be using Attenuator? Or just use multimode from the switch to switch connections that are short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sheet "Cisco SFP Modules for Gigabit Ethernet Applications Data Sheet" says "the minimum cable distance for all SFPs listed (multimode and single-mode fiber) is 6.5 feet (2 m)."

However even though the transmit maximum power is equal to the receive maximum power, for very short distances (5m) I get receive overload warnings which may be due to reflections  (see my question ["1000BASE-LX/LH Receive power level greater than transmit power level"](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46507/1000base-lx-lh-receive-power-level-greater-than-transmit-power-level) )

The datasheet text quoted in the other answer is for the "1000BASE-ZX SFP for Long-Reach Single-Mode Fibers" which have a higher transmit than receive power

The 1000BASE-LX/LH can use SM or MM, however mixed SM and MM cable in the fixed plant causes me a lot of headaches and I would recommended SM with attenuators if needed.

Answer (score 2):

From Cisco documentation:

[Cisco SFP Modules for Gigabit Ethernet Applications Data Sheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/gigabit-ethernet-gbic-sfp-modules/product_data_sheet0900aecd8033f885.html)

> When shorter distances of single-mode fiber (SMF) are used, it might be necessary to insert an inline optical attenuator in the link to avoid overloading the receiver. A 10-dB inline optical attenuator should be inserted between the fiber-optic cable plant and the receiving port on the SFP at each end of the link whenever the fiber-optic cable span loss is less than 8 dB.

My suggestion would be to use the fiber type appropriate to the application.  For distances of 550m or less (allow some swag for jumpers and such), use multimode.  It will be cheaper all around.

---

Update --

[Optical Fiber Standards and Their Applications](https://www.bicsi.org/uploadedfiles/PDFs/Conferences/singapore2010/pre/1-Optical%20Fibre%20Standards-Applications,%20Chris%20Thiam,%20FiberOpto%20Asia.pdf)
[Small form-factor pluggable transceiver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver)

Different SFP types expect certain fiber type/sizes.  While they may work with other types, the operation of single-mode vs multi-mode is different and could impact performance.

[Multi-mode optical fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-mode_optical_fiber)

> The main difference between multi-mode and single-mode optical fiber
>   is that the former has much larger core diameter, typically 50–100
>   micrometers; much larger than the wavelength of the light carried in
>   it. Because of the large core and also the possibility of large
>   numerical aperture, multi-mode fiber has higher "light-gathering"
>   capacity than single-mode fiber. In practical terms, the larger core
>   size simplifies connections and also allows the use of lower-cost
>   electronics such as light-emitting diodes (LEDs) and vertical-cavity
>   surface-emitting lasers (VCSELs) which operate at the 850 nm and 1300
>   nm wavelength (single-mode fibers used in telecommunications typically
>   operate at 1310 or 1550 nm [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver)). However, compared to single-mode
>   fibers, the multi-mode fiber bandwidth–distance product limit is
>   lower. Because multi-mode fiber has a larger core-size than
>   single-mode fiber, it supports more than one propagation mode; hence
>   it is limited by modal dispersion, while single mode is not.

[Single-mode optical fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-mode_optical_fiber)

> Like multi-mode optical fibers, single-mode fibers do exhibit modal
>   dispersion resulting from multiple spatial modes but with narrower
>   modal dispersion.[citation needed] Single-mode fibers are therefore
>   better at retaining the fidelity of each light pulse over longer
>   distances than multi-mode fibers. For these reasons, single-mode
>   fibers can have a higher bandwidth than multi-mode fibers. Equipment
>   for single-mode fiber is more expensive than equipment for multi-mode
>   optical fiber, but the single-mode fiber itself is usually cheaper in
>   bulk.

Regarding cost: There is a cost difference between SFP types and this will contribute to the total cost of a solution and should be considered.  A quick search around the internet and one provider of 1m jumpers, the single-mode jumpers were roughly twice the price of multimode.

Comment: Thank you! I believe that is the route we will take when we redo our jumpers in a few weeks!

Comment: You should check your transceiver's documentation. Long-wave transceivers are designed with little or no overlap in transmit and receive powers, so the receiver may be prone to blinding without attenuation.

Comment: Actually, MM really isn't cheaper than SM for the cabling. The MM optics are cheaper than SM, but the cost of the cabling has achieved parity.

Comment: Also don't some (Cisco in particular) transceivers have transmit attenuation available in their settings? Or maybe I'm getting mixed up with T1/E1 CSU/DSU WICs.

Comment: Reading that document more carefully I believe the paragraph you are quoting only applies to the ZR transcievers. There is advice to use a smaller attenuation for ER transcievers and doesn't seem to be any advice to use an attenutator for LR.

Answer (score 2):

You should never install multi-mode fiber as there is no upside at all with multi-mode fiber. The old saying that multi-mode is cheaper than single mode is simply not true any more.

Furthermore, The spec of 1000BaseLX/10GBaseLR (standard 10km optics for single-mode fibers) states that the maximum tx-power is lower than the maximum rx-power, so you should not need to worry about power levels unless doing long-haul setup.